# How to get mapped drives on remote users session

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, remote-access

I need to get real mapped drives on remote session, I read remote registry for Path and Name but the label (drive letter) are missing in \Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2

If I read HKCU\Network I have only the persistent drive (GPP drive with status Replace are missing).

how do I find the path, the name and the label ?

```
function get-Drives {
        param ( [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $Computername, [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] $SID )
        try {
            $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('USERS', $computerName)
            $RegKey = $Reg.OpenSubKey("$SID\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\MountPoints2")
            $lecteurs = $RegKey.GetSubKeyNames()
            $lecteurs | ?{$_ -notlike '{*}'} | %{
                $RegKey = $Reg.OpenSubKey("$SID\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\MountPoints2\\$_")
                $_LabelFromReg = $regKey.GetValue('_LabelFromReg')
                if ($_LabelFromReg) {
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        Name = $_LabelFromReg
                        Label = ''
                        Path = $_ -replace('#','\')
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't said *why* you need to get real mapped drives for a user's remote session.

Comment: i create a tool software for helpdesk (4000 RDC Sessions)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Mapped drives are generally a per-user setting or defined in a GPO. What does creating a tool software for help desk have to do with getting mapped drives for a remote user's session?

Comment: the User Drive in mounted by GPP, the user know only Label or Name of each drive, but the technician has need the real Path to understand the users, this tool is a link betwen User and technician. because gpedit.msc is so hard to read quickly

Comment: Have user start `cmd.exe` and run command `net use`. This output tells you mapped drives. Trying to determine remotely is error-prone.

Comment: cmd.exe are disable for my users

Comment: I explain in a [blog posting](http://sincealtair.blogspot.com/2009/12/disabling-command-prompt-does-not.html) why doing this does offers no advantages and does not increase security.

Answer (score 1):

Getting mapped drives remotely is error-prone. It is far simpler and less trouble to get the list from the user. Here is a short WSH JScript script you can give to users. Users can run this to get a quick dialog box of mapped drives and locations:

```
// mappedDrives.js

var wshNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
var networkDrives = wshNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives();
var results = "";
for ( var i = 0; i < networkDrives.length; i += 2 ) {
  var resultLine = networkDrives.Item(i) + " -> " + networkDrives.Item(i + 1);
  if ( results != "" ) {
    results += "\r\n" + resultLine;
  }
  else {
    results = resultLine;
  }
}

var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
if ( results != "" ) {
  wshShell.Popup(results, 0, "Mapped Drives");
}
else {
  wshShell.Popup("No mapped drives detected", 0, "Mapped Drives");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As pointed out by @Alban, this doesn't get the current logged in user's mapped drives, only drives mapped by the computer. I'll leave the answer here as it might be useful for somebody that needs that in the future, but it is obviously not what the OP needed.

Assuming your Helpdesk has access to remote WMI calls you could do this with the `Win32_LogicalDisk` `WMI` class. Mapped drives are `DriveType` 4, so filter for that, and return `DeviceID`, `ProviderName`, and `VolumeName`. Or rename them for ease of reading like:

```psh
gwmi -class win32_logicaldisk -Computer $ComputerName | Where{$_.DriveType -eq 4} | select @{n='DriveLetter';e={$_.DeviceID}},VolumeName,@{n='NetworkPath';e={$_.ProviderName}}
```

Simple enough right? Here's what I got running it against my local computer:

```psh
DriveLetter        VolumeName          NetworkPath
-----------        ----------          -----------
X:                 OSDisk              \\localhost\c$\temp
```

I'm fairly certain that should work against a remote computer for any currently mapped drives.

Comment: this command get computer mapped drive, not Users Session Mapped drive